# Add filter to table Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I followed this tutorial to have a sortable table with a search box http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax.
Thats works fine, but now a I need to add a filter to the table. When you click a field value, por example the author, the table must show only the records of that author.
I have the following:

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_issue, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :do_vote, :do_watch]
  before_action :current_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :index, :new, :create, :post_comment, :do_vote, :do_watch]
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @issues = Issue.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end
...
```

How can I add my filter there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `where(author: params[:author])` to your Issue query.

```ruby
@issues = Issue
  .search(params[:search])
  .where(author: params[:author])
  .order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

Comment: I assume you have an `author` column in your `issues` table.

Comment: yes. I do that with another field call "tipo", but at first its null:
Processing by IssuesController#index as HTML
  Rendering issues/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Issue Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "issues".* FROM "issues" WHERE "issues"."tipo" IS NULL ORDER BY title asc LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 5], ["OFFSET", 0]]

how can i put it to get all ? @light.wave

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to "get all" of the Issues? But you asked for a way to filter on the author. What exactly do you really want? Can you clarify your question?